# Create Postgres function that concats and returns more than one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have played around with this for a few hours and it seems to be going over my head.

I am a novice at SQL and am attempting to create a simple function to concat first_name and last_name rows into a staff_fname table.

Using this code returns the results just fine and populates staff_fname, concatenating each first name and last name entry from the source table:

```
SELECT
CONCAT (first_name, ' ', last_name) INTO staff_fname
FROM staff;
```

However, when I try to insert this into a function, it does not work properly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION connames()
RETURNS varchar(90)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE staff_fname varchar(90);
BEGIN
    SELECT
    CONCAT (first_name, ‘ ’, last_name) INTO staff_fname
    FROM staff;

    RETURN staff_fname;
END;
$$;
```

When I try to call the function connames(), it only concats and returns one row (the first row). I have tried playing around with LOOP, RETURNS SETOF, and RETURN QUERY to no avail. I am sure it is simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can return a TABLE and use just SQL instead of plpgsql. Check the manual for further details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE

Comment: By the way, you can also wrap this into a VIEW, no need for a function at all.

Comment: CREATE VIEW my_view_name AS
SELECT
    CONCAT (first_name, ‘ ’, last_name) AS staff_fname
FROM staff;

Comment: I tried creating a table (line 2 changed to RETURNS TABLE(staff_fname)) and changing the language to sql but get a syntax error. Unfortunately the project I am working on calls for a function, so I cannot use a view.

Comment: You omitted the column type. Try `RETURNS TABLE(staff_fname text)` or `RETURNS SETOF text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be simple using language SQL

```sql
create or replace function connames() returns setof text as 
$$
  select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) from staff;
$$
language sql stable;
```

Comment: You are beautiful and a saint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be like

```
create or replace function connames()
returns setof text as 
$$
begin
 return query select CONCAT (first_name,' ', last_name) FROM staff;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and execution

```
select connames() into staff_fname;
```

Comment: Why is dynamic SQL needed?

Comment: there's no need in this case, i use it for extensibility so parameters could be added afterwards.